# What is wrong with this line of code with pipe %>%?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I'm trying to run.

```
1:10 %>% replace(`>`(.,4), 999)
Error in replace(`1:10`, . > 4, 999) : object '.' not found
```

Maybe I've been using `.` wrong all this time, so I go read the `magrittr` documentation. I learned about using `{}` to override passing `.` as the first argument.

So now I try

```
1:10 %>% {replace(., `>`(.,4), 999)}
Error in replace(`1:10`, . > 4, 999) : object '.' not found
```

Nope, still doesn't work. I run the example code given for `{}` (page 9)

```
1:10 %>% {c(min(.), max(.))}
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '.' not found
```

Example code doesn't even work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not able to reproduce the error with `magrittr_1.5`

Comment: @akrun There was something wrong with the version of pipe imported via `library(dplyr)`. Updating `dplyr` and `magrittr` did the trick. I swear I must have updated `dplyr` less than a month ago...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with @Akrun in not being able to reproduce the error, but

```
1:10 %>% replace(.>4,999)
```

seems simpler and easier to read. (This is in a clean session with `magrittr` version 1.5, no other non-base packages loaded, nothing else in the workspace.)

*Side comment: I assume this is part of a longer/more complicated workflow.  If you're just replacing `replace(x,x>4,999)` with `x %>% replace(.>4,999)` I'm not sure I see the point ...*

Comment: I initially thought that `.` didn't play nice with unary functions so I called `>` with quotes. Actual workflow doesn't involve a numeric vector. Problem solved. There was something wrong with the version of pipe imported via `library(dplyr)`. Updating `dplyr` and `magrittr` did the trick.

Comment: @Vlo Fwiw, `>` is binary, not unary.

Comment: @Frank Trying to name the type of function you define with `%foo%`. What is the name again?

Comment: @Vlo That's "binary", yup. Not sure where in the R lang definition this unique use of the `%foo%` syntax is mentioned.

Comment: @Frank `%foo%` can be called via "%foo%"(arg1, arg2) or like arg1 %foo% arg2. The pipe operator along with +, -, ^, etc are all infix (the word I was looking for) functions